# Reverse JSON Grails/Groovy

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I have a JSON which looks like :

```
[
 { Name: "mike",
   Address: "xyz"
   Parent: {
        NAme: "john"
        Address: "xyz"
        Parent: {
            NAme: "Ross"
            Adress: "asdsa"
        }     
   }
]
```

I want to reverse it such that it looks like :

```
[
  { Name: "Ross",
       Address: "adsad"
       child: {
            NAme: "john"
            Address: "xyz"
            child: {
                NAme: "Mike"
                Adress: "xyz"
            }     
       }
    ]
```

What would be the best way to reverse this using (something generic i.e. the json can be much bigger with more parent objects)?

Comment: You want to always make a last child to be a parent ?

Comment: yes. you mean the other way round